# Filter Chain Class

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, servlet

Всем привет! Прошу помочь разобратся с кодом ..

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    System.out.printf("LoginFilter.doFilter(): requestURI = %s; ", requestURI);

    String loggedInToken = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute(LoginConstants.LOGIN_FLAG);

    if (loggedInToken != null) {
        // User is logged in, continue processing, override getRemoteUser in request object.
        System.out.printf("user is %s%n", loggedInToken);
        chain.doFilter(new LoginFilterHTTPServletRequest((HttpServletRequest) req, loggedInToken), resp);
        return;
    }
```

===============================================

Непонятна логика данной строки.. 
После проверки "loggedInToken != null" будет распечатан юсер, после чего я потерялся.. Буду рад каким то идеям..

```
    chain.doFilter(new LoginFilterHTTPServletRequest((HttpServletRequest) req, loggedInToken), resp);
        return;
```

Comment: Дальше идёт вызов следующего фильтра в цепочке (chain - цепь) фильтров.Фильтров может быть несколько и они выстраиваются в очередь. Что бы перейти к следующему фильтру или к сервлету  (если данный фильтр последний) вызывается `chain.doFilter()`. Если не вызывать `chain`, то обработка запроса завершится на этом фильтре. Вот тут пояснение с картинками, хотя если аглицкий не знаете совсем, то и картинки не помогут. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28959/filters.htm

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, с англиским отлично. Прочту..

Comment: Кроме того фильтр может подменять `request` и `response`, обычно передавая следующему фильтру свои обёртки (wrapper) вокруг полученных самим `request` и `response`. Что мы и наблюдаем на примере `LoginFilterHTTPServletRequest`. Вероятно данный фильтр хочет внедрить свойство `loggedInToken` в `request`. В стандартном request нет такого свойства, поэтому подменяет его своим wrapper-ом.

Comment: Можеш ли дать пример того зачем нужно подменять полученные Request & Response ?

Comment: Не могу. Самому никогда не было нужды подменять. А примеры высосанные из пальца в книжках лучше написаны.

Comment: Сергей еше вопрос.. 
doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response), принимает 2 типа.. В моём примере кода идет передача ServletResponse и 
LoginFilterHTTPServletRequest которому передаётся ServletReuqest
Конвертированный в HTTPServletRequest с передачей loggedInToken типа String.. Насколько я вижу тут один параметр типа LoginFilterHTTPServletRequest разве тут недолжно быть не совпаденние типов с ServletRequest типом ?

Comment: Посмотрите код `LoginFilterHTTPServletRequest` он должен наследоваться от `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper`, который в свою очередь является реализацией `HttpServletRequest` и `ServletRequest`. Как раз то, что нужно в `chain.doFilter`

Comment: Ок. Спасибо я разберу это всё.